# Modifying a set within a recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion, set

I'm trying to write a program to check if a particular word can be made using a given "boggle board". There full details of the challenge are here: [Boggle Word Checker](https://www.codewars.com/kata/57680d0128ed87c94f000bfd/train/python).

Basically, the program is supposed find the first letter of a word, on the board, and then check if any of the adjacent letters to it on the board match the next letter of the word.

This is what I've got so far (not pretty I know):

```
def pos(board, x, y):
    # function to get value from a grid, but return None if not on grid,to
    # prevent wraparound
    if x >= 0 and y >= 0 and x < len(board[0]) and y < len(board):
        return board[y][x]
    else:
        return None

def surrounds(board, x, y):
    # make a dictionary which to store the positions and values of adjacent
    # letters on board, given a single postision as input
    return {
        (x-1,y-1) : pos(board,x-1,y-1), #aboveLeft
        (x,y-1) : pos(board,x,y-1),     #aboveMiddle etc...
        (x+1,y-1) : pos(board,x+1,y-1),
        (x-1,y) : pos(board,x-1,y),
        (x+1,y) : pos(board,x+1,y),
        (x-1,y+1) : pos(board,x-1,y+1),
        (x,y+1) : pos(board,x,y+1),
        (x+1,y+1) : pos(board,x+1,y+1)
    }

def find_word(board, word):
    # initialise
    listOfCoords = []

    # find all occurrences of the first letter, and store their board
    # position in a list
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[0])):
            if board[i][j] == word[0]:
                listOfCoords.append([j,i])

    print('list of ' + word[0] + 's on board:')
    print(listOfCoords)
    print()

    # if word is only 1 letter long then we can return True at this point
    if listOfCoords and len(word) == 1:
        return True

    # otherwise we move on to look for the second letter
    return findnext(board,word,listOfCoords)

def findnext(board, word, mylist):
    for x, y in mylist:
        print("Current coords: {},{}\n".format(x,y))
        surroundings = surrounds(board,x,y)

        listFounds = []

        for k, v in surroundings.items():

            if v == word[1]:
                print("{} found at {}".format(v,k))
                print()

                if len(word) == 2:
                    print()
                    return True

                listFounds.append(k)

                if findnext(board, word[1:], listFounds) == True:
                    return True
    return False

testBoard = [
      ["E","A","R","A"],
      ["N","L","E","C"],
      ["I","A","I","S"],
      ["B","Y","O","R"]
    ]

print(find_word(testBoard, "CEREAL"))
```

However, I've encountered a problem, as the challenge specifies that no position on the board can be used more than once. Therefore, in the above example, the program should return False for "CEREAL", but mine returns True.

I was thinking a way around this could be to use a set, which adds the coordinates to the set once a next letter is found. However I'm a bit lost as to where I would need to create the empty set, and how it would work with all the loops and recursion going on...

For example, let's say we were looking for "CEREAL" on a different board, which has 2 Es adjacent to C. let's say the first path only leads to CER and the other leads to CEREAL. If we go down the CER path first, the positions for it would be added to the set, and I would somehow need to remove them again before it goes down the CEREAL path.

I'm struggling to think how to implement this in my program.

Comment: @ParthShah in the current form this post would not be [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on CR. Please familiarize yourself with the site before recommending it to users.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ gotcha. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an array of booleans the size of the board all set to False. When you use a letter and call your function recursively, set the cell to True for the used letter. When returning from the recursive call, set the cell value back to False. You should only use letters with False values indicating that they have not been previously used.

Alternatively, you can replace the used letter by None after keeping the letter in a temporary variable then do the recursive call. Upon the return from the recursive call put back the value of the cell from the temp variable.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach IMO. Since the board looks relatively small, it might be easier to just make a copy of it at each level of recursion before changing it, and pass that on to the next level, which would alleviate the need to restore it before returning from each one.

Comment: @martineau Ton nom sonne Français. Your approach is somewhat more elegant. The problem is that a copy needs to be made, then modified, defeating the purpose IMHO.

Comment: Juste une coïncidence. What purpose would doing so defeat?

Comment: @martineau In principle your proposed approach is simpler and cleaner, but unfortunately the copying and modification does not save much coding That said, on a larger board, copies of the board could be sent to subprocesses for parallel processing.

Comment: It might be slightly less error-prone as well as require less code especially if an intermediate function has multiple return paths. Actually the fact that making copies would also facilitate concurrency did occur to me, but I didn't mention it because it seemed too off-topic.

Comment: @martineau, well there is some give or take here. You might be right :-). So, no French blood? Just a coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Find the 1st character match against the board
2. Once a match is found, do a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) with [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) till you completely match the word or exhaust the search due to mismatch.
3. If complete match is not found in above step, continue scanning the board. (i.e. go to step 1) for the next character that matches on the board.
4. If a match is found in step 3, report success.

This solution works for `NxM` board as well.

```py
def is_within_bounds(row, col, row_dim, col_dim):
    return row >= 0 and row < row_dim and col >= 0 and col < col_dim


def get_neighbors(row, col, row_dim, col_dim):
    for r_offset in (-1, 0, 1):
        for c_offset in (-1, 0, 1):
            if r_offset == 0 and c_offset == 0:
                continue
            r_new = row + r_offset
            c_new = col + c_offset
            if is_within_bounds(r_new, c_new, row_dim, col_dim):
                yield (r_new, c_new)


def is_word_found(board, word, row, col, visited):
    if word[0] != board[row][col]:
        return False
    if len(word) == 1:
        return True
    for neighbor in get_neighbors(row, col, len(board), len(board[0])):
        if neighbor not in visited:
            visited.add(neighbor)
            if is_word_found(board, word[1:], neighbor[0], neighbor[1], visited):
                return True
            visited.remove(neighbor)
    return False


def find_word(board, word):
    for row in range(len(board)):
        for col in range(len(board[0])):
            if word[0] != board[row][col]:
                continue
            if is_word_found(board, word, row, col, set()):
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on this site. Please add some kind of an explanation of what it does or how it works.

Comment: @martineau Done.

Comment: Much improved…but how exactly is the code addressing the OP's question with respect to modifying the set in a recursive function? (I think I know, but feel that needs to be addressed in your answer. I suspect it's just an implementation of @Tarik's answer.

Comment: I didn't read Tarik's answer before till you pointed out. That's all I have to say @martineau